# set in location and if in another location

Tags: nginx, http-live-streaming

I have 2 locations in nginx.conf i want to give access with .ts extention only if you have accessed through .m3u8 otherwise it will return 403.

So basically http://xxx/hello.m3u8 Will grant you access to play the .ts list inside.
But trying to access the chunks alone like in http://xxx/hello-123.ts wouldn't work.
Making the access to cache in period time would also be fine.
This is the code i have come to so far, help would be appreciated.

```
location ~ \.m3u8 {
    root /mnt/hls;
    add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
    set $access 1;
}
location ~ \.ts {
    if ($access = "") {
        return 403;
    }
    root /mnt/hls;
    add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
}
```

Comment: This code will not work, because you have two separate requests. One for `m3u8` file and second for `ts` file, and they are completely unrelated for server.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, i understand what you are saying and in matter fact you are right, but yet again i'm asking for how-to-do with the result as my request, i could the change the code completely but i want the result. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't block the access to the `.ts` segments if you want to be able to play them back. If you're looking for some form of DRM you could use token-based authentication coupled with segment encryption with a rotating key served over HTTPS. This will make it harder but not impossible to record your content.

Implementing an authentication module in Nginx is pretty easy. See the tutorial and example project here: [Nginx Auth Token Module](https://github.com/abedra/nginx-auth-token-module).